# Modal body text won't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

These pesky modals are at it again.  I can get my modal to pop up but for some bizarre reason, the text in its body just doesn't show.  What's the deal?  Here's the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Modal text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you reproduce it using a pen?

Comment: <p>{Modal text}.</p> use {} to show text, if it is js variable, if you want see "Modal text." it self might be style issue

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to use codepen.

Comment: Okay, signed up for code pen and it was simply enough.  Yes, I can.  And I actually just figured out the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the version of Bootstrap that you're using?

I just swapped your code out for an existing dialog on Codepen that uses Bootstrap 4.0.0 and it works:

https://codepen.io/richjava/pen/JxxyWP

```
<!-- basic modal -->
<!-- <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->

<div id="basicModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Modal text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```